# How can i get object_list in django middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I am writing one middleware class to handle pagination in django.

I am getting issue when user delete entry in ListView and page number is lost. So, i have to check how many pages for that request and adjust page number to reduce issue 404 error. I can get ClassBase Name, model name but cant get object_list data.

my code is:

```
url = request.path
resolver_match = resolve(url)
func = resolver_match.func
module = func.__module__
view_name = func.__name__
clss = get_class( '{0}.{1}'.format( module, view_name ) )
```

I want to count the current page of that request.
Please suggest to get it.

Thanks,

ThanhTruong

Comment: We don't get the question. Please show us more code and/or explain your question with examples.

Comment: How can i get list_object in that middleware code ?

Comment: I asked for more code and/or a better explanation. I did not say "just repeat the same question".

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to handle pagination in a base view or a mixin. See ListView for an example.

Comment: You don't have to change them: just use multiple inheritance